# How to get this trigger to put all values in rich text field?

Tags: trigger

The following trigger retrieves a list of members and is supposed to put all of them in a field on the parent account record in a field named  "BOG_Members_List__c ". It currently only puts the last one of the list. How to get it to put all of them? (yes, the query returns more than one person. I checked.)

```
trigger trgr_Update_BOG_Members_List on BOG_Membership__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    ID currID;
    for(BOG_Membership__c a: Trigger.new){
        currID = a.Contact__r.AccountId;
     }     

    List<AggregateResult> aggregates = [
    SELECT Contact__r.AccountId , Contact__r.FirstName , Contact__r.LastName 
        FROM BOG_Membership__c 
        WHERE Contact__r.AccountId = '0012000000fyND0'
        GROUP BY Contact__r.AccountId, Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName

];

Map<Id, Account> parentRecords = new Map<Id, Account>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : aggregates)
{

    Id parentId = (Id)aggregate.get('accountId');
    String firstName = (String)aggregate.get('FirstName');
    String lastName = (String)aggregate.get('LastName');

    parentRecords.put(parentId, new Account(
    Id = parentId, BOG_Members_List__c = firstName + ' ' + lastName + '<br />'
    ));
}
update parentRecords.values();
}
```

Comment: You know how to debug things, right?  Try putting some debug statements in there to see if it's iterating over what you think it's iterating over, and whether the accountId is what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this that replaces the `Account` object in the `parentRecords` map every time round the loop:

```
parentRecords.put(parentId, new Account(
        Id = parentId,
        BOG_Members_List__c = firstName + ' ' + lastName + '<br />'
        ));
```

with this that appends to the field of a single Account object:

```
Account a = parentRecords.get(parentId);
if (a == null) parentRecords.put(new Account(Id = parentId, BOG_Members_List__c = ''));
a.BOG_Members_List__c += firstName + ' ' + lastName + '<br />';
```

Comment: It's giving me an error "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.trgr_Update_BOG_Members_List: line 29, column 1" on this line a. BOG_Members_List__c += firstName + ' ' + lastName + '<br />';

Comment: I modified the code based on what you did and it works. Many thanks Keith